# React Native: I am getting error while trying to get image from https://cataas.com api

Tags: react-native, fetch

I am getting SyntaxError: Json Parse error: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'

I'm using https://cataas.com api for a react native app,  my task is to  generate a list of random kitten images. I tried using fetch method, but also i get error sorce.uri should not be an empty string. How can i solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
  Image, 
  StyleSheet,
  Text, 
  View,
  FlatList 
} from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
 state = {
      photos: '',
    }


componentDidMount() {
   fetch('https://cataas.com/cat?width=100')
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(data => {
       this.setState({
           photos: data
         })
         .catch(err => {
           console.log('error', err);
           alert(err)
         })
     })
}


render() {
    console.log(this.state.photos)
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image 
          source={{url: this.state.photos}} 
          style={{height: 100, width: 100}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  }
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code

Replace `url` with `uri` as in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image)

```
<Image 
   source={{uri: this.state.photos}} 
   style={{height: 100, width: 100}}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it says that sourse.uri should not be an ampty string. Hmm does that means that it gets html data from api or something?
I don't know if that is right way to fetch images from api.

Comment: You can set default image string url in your state rather than empty string

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call this api manually, you could directly use the link in the Image component :

```
<Image 
  source={{uri: "https://picsum.photos/100/100"}} 
  style={{height: 100, width: 100}}
/>
```

**EDIT:**

Ok it's not as easy as I thought !

I created a first basic version : https://snack.expo.io/@sanjar/so-53434400

And contrary to what I thought it's always the same picture that is displayed.
It's because of react-native cache system that see the same url and decide to not execute the http request again.
then I checked the doc and found[a way to fix this issue, but for ios only](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#cache-control-ios-only) 
I just had to change :

```
source={{uri: "https://source.unsplash.com/random"}}
```

by :

```
source={{uri: "https://source.unsplash.com/random", cache: 'reload'}}
```

It should work on ios (I don't have a mac with me now), for android I don't know yet, I'll probably investigate later.

Comment: That way all works, but I need to render list of random pictures from that api.

Comment: if you have a list of Image calling a random api, each Image will execute it own http request and will get a different picture.

Comment: Unfortunately, my task is to fetch them from api :(

Comment: Thank you! Me neither have a mac, so I'll will try this on android, hope this will work. Thank you again!